# Can mongodb do this SQL?

Tags: mongodb

In MySQL Query:

```
UPDATE $TABLE SET `col1`=`col2` WHERE 1;
UPDATE $TABLE SET `col1`=IF(`col1`>100, `col1`-100, `col1`) WHERE 1;
```

Can MongoDB do like this?

Comment: Have you read the [Mongo to SQL comparison](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-comparison/) documentation?

Comment: You can answer your own question if you read this http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/

Comment: You would do better to "describe" your document problem rather than post an "abstract" way of how you think you do it with SQL.

Comment: @LewisNorton Probably isn't going to help anyone unless the problem is explained. That documentation source, while useful, is **very** limited to basic explanations. I think comments should "guide" and not "critique".

Answer (score 1):

What you appear to want to do is a conditional update - update the document based on its current state. MongoDB only has very limited support for this. See the [update operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/) for details.

For the first query, it would be best to retrieve the documents, change them, and then save them. Unless your intention is not to copy the field but to rename it. Then you can use [$rename](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/#up._S_rename).

For the second, it would be possible with this query:

```
db.collection.update( 
     { field1: { $gt: 100} },
     { $inc: { field1, -100 },
     { multi: true} 
);
```

By the way: You can also use the same pattern in SQL. It would likely work faster than using an if-condition.

```
UPDATE $TABLE SET `col1`=`col1`-100 WHERE `col1 ` > 100
```

Comment: Thank you!  The first query no way?I realy need it,for Atomic operation.
in mysql: select `col2` from $table then  update col1=$col2  but it is not a atomic operation

Comment: @HengYiHuang You should open a new question where you explain why you want to do this. Maybe we can find an alternative solution. But in order to do so we need to know the bigger picture of what you are trying to achieve. Keep in mind that MongoDB is not a drop-in replacement for MySQL. Trying to build the exactly same structures 1:1 in MongoDB rarely ends well. To find a good solution in MongoDB you need to take a step back, look at the actual business requirements, forget everything you know about SQL and find a document-oriented solution.